# outofmemory exception in android

Tags: android

I have two activities in my application *Activity A* and *Activity B*. From *Activity A* I am going to *Activity B*.

What will happen to my application if the *Activity B* throws an `OutOfMemory` error? Will the application show *Activity A*?

Answer (score 0):

It will collapse. I had this problem and it did.

Answer (score 0):

Well, B can handle the exception appropriately, but if it doesn't, then your app will crash, taking out A and B alike.